# Spring Framework XML configuration metadata, and Namespaces

Tags: java, xml, spring, namespaces, xsd

I've been studying the configuration of metadata information to use Spring, and I realized that I needed to delve a bit into XML. I have doubts about the referral schemes in XML files. So far, all I know (I guess...), is as follows:

1. I read that the use of namespaces is useful for separating
   markup elements in an XML document, thus avoiding conflicts in
   markup ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)).
2. The use of URIs for naming Namespaces is seen as a standard, not
   meaning that a file will be searched for in a web address, for
   example ([source](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html) - in "What Do Namespace Names Point At?").
3. The declaration of a namespace is made with the use of a reserved
   attribute, "xmlns".
4. Namespaces use prefixes (also referred to as alias), but the use of
   prefixes is not required for marking various sub-elements ([source](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html) - in "Beautification").

Things start to get confused when I encounter the following piece of markup:

```
<element xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform
                             http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform.xsd
                             http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
                             http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml.xsd">
</element>
```

According to many sources (including [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_schemaLocation)), referencing XSD schemas is made using (seemingly to me) Namespaces, which as has been said, do not point to anything, no files or anything really.

It is said in [session 2.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) that vocabularies are identified and used by Namespace, giving me to understand that the name "schemaLocation" is a reserved word and used with the chosen prefix "xsi". I would like to know a few things pertaining to the facts presented here:

- What is the name given to "schemaLocation", placed after the prefix
  used? Is that named as "attribute"? If so, it is an attribute of what?
- The Spring recognizes certain namespaces differently, performing its
  own logic on top of it, or is it possible that Namespaces really
  point to physical files in an address?
- The use of "xsi: schemaLocation" can be done without a declaration of
  use of a namespace with the prefix "xsi"?

For example:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="..... http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">
```

This snippet was taken from the book "Getting Started with Spring Framework - Second Edition", chapter 3, page 112.

- Could it be that the author left out the declaration "xmlns: xsi
  ..."? If he did not omit, then this code would be wrong? Or is this
  not necessary be written?

### EDIT

I wish if a response is given to my question, it includes the definition, differences, and applicability of the following:

- QNames.
- Expanded Names.
- Global Attributes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1) What is the name given to "schemaLocation", placed after the prefix used? Is that named as "attribute"? If so, it is an attribute of what? [See here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#schemaLocation)

> In an instance document, the attribute xsi:schemaLocation provides hints from the author to a processor regarding the location of schema documents.
>
> The schemaLocation attribute value consists of one or more pairs of
>   URI references, separated by white space. The first member of each
>   pair is a namespace name, and the second member of the pair is a hint
>   describing where to find an appropriate schema document for that
>   namespace. The presence of these hints does not require the processor
>   to obtain or use the cited schema documents, and the processor is free
>   to use other schemas obtained by any suitable means, or to use no
>   schema at all.

2) The Spring recognizes certain namespaces differently, performing its own logic on top of it, or is it possible that Namespaces really point to physical files in an address?

Spring uses

**META-INF/spring.schemas**

1. re-maps(*) schemalocation to a xsd inside the library
2. (abstract) only re-mapped versions are supported by this library
3. The properties file called 'spring.schemas' contains a mapping of XML Schema locations

**META-INF/spring.handlers**

1. provides namespace handler classes for specific namespaces
2. the namespace handler class provides the parser logic to parse spring-batch beans, like job, step, etc.

3) The use of "xsi: schemaLocation" can be done without a declaration of use of a namespace with the prefix "xsi"?

the prefix is ​​mandatory (XML Standards)

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Some things were explained clearly, others were not well explained, I guess. I feel that your answer helped, but it was missing something. Still, thanks for your help, really.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your questions correctly; ask if this fails to tell you wnat you want to know.

> What is the name given to "schemaLocation", placed after the prefix used?

When dealing with namespaces, it's best to overcome the idea that the term *name* has a single or simple meaning.  When you ask "What is the name ..." your words assume that there is some single thing that is the *name* of the attribute.  There isn't.  There are several different kinds of names involved here; the two most important are the *qualified name* (what you write in the XML document) and the *expanded name* (what most processes use to decide whether they are responsible for doing something with a given part of your XML document).

In the example you give, the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute on the `element` element has the *qualified name* (or *QName*) `xsi:schemaLocation`.  A qualified name may consist (as here) of a *namespace prefix* (here `xsi`), a colon, and a *local name* (here `schemaLocation`).

In a document that conforms to [the W3C Namespaces Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/),  namespace prefixes are bound to *namespace names* using namespace declarations (sometimes also called namespace attributes).  In the example you give, the namespace declaration

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

binds the prefix `xs` to the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. In context, therefore, the QName `xsi:schemaLocation` denotes the *expanded name* `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation`.

> Is that named as "attribute"?

This one is more complicated than it looks; the answer is "yes" and "no".

Yes, it's an attribute, in the XML sense.  That is, the string

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

matches the grammar for the non-terminal *attribute* in the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/), and it appears in an appropriate context.

But because it's a namespace declaration, it's not a 'normal' attribute, and most people prefer to regard it as not being an attribute.  The [attributes] property in the [XML Information Set](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/) does not include it (the [namespace attributes] property does), and the XPath `attribute` axis won't match it.

> If so, it is an attribute of what?

All XML attributes are attributes of their host element (here, the element whose name is `element`).

Note that the word *attribute* is used with different meanings in different parts of information technology; the attributes on an element in an XML document do not necessarily have any relation at all to the attributes discussed in a relational model of the information.

> The Spring recognizes certain namespaces differently, performing its own logic on top of it, or is it possible that Namespaces really point to physical files in an address?

The function of namespace names is to be distinct from each other, so that processing software can distinguish different elements and attributes which may have the same local name but belong to different namespaces.  (This works only because people know not to use namespace URIs for parts of URI space they don't control, when they are naming new elements.)

So no, in general, namespace names do not normally point at files on any machine.  (Since they are URIs, of course, the owner of the relevant server may configure the server to return a document describing the namespace and its usage, when people dereference the namespace URI.  Most sane people regard this as good practice.)

A complex piece of software which pays attention to several namespaces may well use namespace names to point to appropriate locations in its data structures or in the file system it's using.  But that's not your concern, unless you are maintaining such a piece of software.

> The use of "xsi: schemaLocation" can be done without a declaration of use of a namespace with the prefix "xsi"?
>   For example:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation=".....    
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">
```

> This snippet was taken from the book "Getting Started with Spring Framework - Second Edition", chapter 3, page 112.
>
> Could it be that the author left out the declaration "xmlns: xsi ..."? If he did not omit, then this code would be wrong? Or is this not necessary be written?

Namespace declarations are inherited from ancestor elements, so if the `beans` element you give occurs as the descendant of an element which carries an appropriate declaration for the namespace prefix `xsi`, then the XML fragment you give conforms to the XML Namespaces spec.  If there is no such ancestor element, then the fragment is not namespace-well-formed XML.

For purposes of the XSD specification (which defines the namespace whose prefix is conventionally `xsi`), there is no need for the prefix in question to be `xsi` -- any appropriately bound prefix will do.  XSD-aware software understands XSD markup by recognizing its expanded name, not its qualified name.

Comment: I've been researching QNames, Expanded Names, and Global Attributes. You told me that QNames are made up of three things. I read that it receives another name, Expanded Name. Could You  edit your answer to better explain the definitions of QNames, Expanded Names, and Global Attributes, also pointing out their differences, and where they are used? Your answer was really, really good, but some things are still not very clear. I just wish that these terms were defined and differentiated in a clear and didactic manner, if possible. Thank you.